# Powershell: align right for a column value from Select-Object in Format-Table format

Tags: powershell

I have the following array value $outData with several columns. I am not sure how I align some columns right?

```
$outData | Select-Object `
      Name `
      @{Name="Freespace(byte)"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.FreeSpace}}, '
      .... # other colums `
 | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

It works fine. However, when I tried to use align for the freespace column to right:

```
      @{Name="Freespace(byte)"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f $_.FreeSpace}; align="right"}, '
```

I got error message "Specified method is not supported". Not sure if there is any way to align the value to right?

Comment: Have a working command we can reproduce this with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The align directive goes in a hashtable that is specified to the Format-Table cmdlet.  IOW, align is not a supported hashtable entry for Select-Object.  So make sure to do your formatting via hashtables in the hashtable passed to Format-Table e.g.:

```
gps | select name,pm | format-table @{n='Name';e={$_.Name};align='right'},PM
```

or in your case:

```
$outData | Format-Table Name,
                  @{n="Freespace(byte)";e={"{0:N0}" -f $_.FreeSpace};a="right"}
```

Comment: I tried Select with a="right", but it is still not working. However, if I remove it, the Select works fine (as same as Select-Object).

Comment: by the way, my $outDate is initialized like $outData=@{""}; and populated from wmi objects

Comment: Reread the proposed answer. I had a copy/paste error.  :-) The align directive is *not* supported for hashtables used with Select-Object. It is supported for hashtables used with Format-Table.

Answer (score 4):

Given the updates to Powershell in the last 8 years, this answer may not have existed in '10.

The trick is to assign a number of columns within the calculated expression's format block `{0:N0}`, once assigned, it will align the column to the right.

In the original example, include **`,15`** as part of the number formatting:

```
@{Name="Freespace(byte)"; Expression={"{0,15:N0}" -f $_.FreeSpace}}
```

I generally use the character count of the Name= value to ensure the entire name is visible.

Comment: Use a `-15` to left align.
More details here:
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Answer (score 0):

here is an ugly looking one liner that builds from several other threads:

`Get-WmiObject win32_LogicalDisk | where { $_.DriveType -eq 3 } | Format-Table DeviceID,VolumeName,@{N="Size";E={'{0:N0}' -f $_.Size};a="right"},@{N="FreeSpace";E={'{0:N0}' -f $_.FreeSpace};a="right"},@{N="Used";E={'{0:N0}' -f ($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace)};a="right"}`

Comment: Hi notStanley, Welcome to SO!
Look like an interesting one-liner, but an explanation as to what it does would be much more helpful!